# Js mouseClick event seems to fire on the wrong emelent

Tags: javascript

I have a simple div to which I'm adding a child. I'm trying to calculate the child's location with evt.clientX and clientY. Instead i seem to be getting the coordinates of the containing element even tho the function is on the divs.

How could i get the click event for the divs instead of the parent? I don't know much about event inheritance if that is even what it's called.

Here is the code:

```js
function initRipple() {

  //qck define
  let rcont;

  rcont = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('ripple'));

  rcont.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
      ripple(el, evt);
    });
  });

}

function ripple(el, evt) {

  // qck def
  let cir, x, y;

  // assign values
  cir = document.createElement('div');
  x = evt.clientX;
  y = evt.clientY;

  // modify circle attributes / position
  cir.classList.add('ripple-bubble');
  cir.style.left = `${ x - 12 }px`;
  cir.style.top = `${ y - 12 }px`;

  cir.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
    let oldChild = el.removeChild(cir);
  });

  el.appendChild(cir);

}


initRipple();
```

```css
body {background-color: #555}

#tablinks {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#tablinks #tablinks-line {
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 24px;
  background-color: #6DADFF;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

#tablinks .tablink {
  height: 56px;
  line-height: 56px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

#tablinks .tablink.active {
  color: #fff;
}

#tablinks .tablink a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 56px;
  line-height: 56px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 24px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: inherit;
  outline: none;
  font-family: robotomedium;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.ripple {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ripple .ripple-bubble {
  animation: ripple-effect 1s ease forwards;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

@keyframes ripple-effect {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(12);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="tablinks">

  <li class="tablink ripple"><a href="#">TAB 1</a></li>
  <!--
     -->
  <li class="tablink ripple"><a href="#">TAB 2</a></li>
  <!--
     -->
  <li class="tablink ripple"><a href="#t">TAB 3</a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that clientX is relative to the whole page, not to the event.

A quick solution would be to change the computation of x to susbtract the x position of your element.

```
x = evt.clientX;
y = evt.clientY;
const rect = evt.target.getBoundingClientRect()
x -= rect.x;
y -= rect.y;
```

Here is a working pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WMWZWd

Comment: Thanks :) i would hope they made a function that gives coords relative to an element by now but this works nicely. Thanks once again.